# How to pass a JavaScript object to another JavaScript script created from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, javascript-objects

I am working on a single page web app and I'm working with JavaScript objects for the first time. My index page has a menu button which populates in an element in the body using AJAX. That AJAX call returns a button and which requires it's own javascript. My issue is that I can't access the DataEntryObj object that I created in the original script from the JavaScript generated from the AJAX call. When I console log the object, it returns the text used to create the object rather than an object itself. What's going on?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...menu
    <button type="button" id="loadElement"></button>
    ...end of menu
    <div id="response"></div>
    <script> 
      //data Object
      var DataEntryObj = function(){
        this.dataArray = [[0,1,2,3,4]];
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loadElement').click(function(){
          var dataObject = new DataEntryObj();
          console.log(DataEntryObj);
          //this AJAX call works
          $.post("php/entries/loadElement.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
          });
        });
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

loadElement.php

```
...HTML
<button type="button" id="loadSubElement"></button>
<div id="subResponse"></div>
...end of HTML
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#loadSubElement').click(function(){
      //this AJAX call doesn't work
      $.post("php/entries/another.php", {array : DataEntryObj.dataArray}, function(data){
        $('#subResponse').html(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(dataObject );` ?

Comment: @dandavis console.log(dataObject ); returns the text used to create the object rather than an object itself.

Comment: @NateMay -I can help but wonder that when you typed `console.log(DataEntryObj);` if it wasn't actually your intention to write `console.log(DataObj);` One of them is the function that creates the data, while the other is the data itself.

Comment: are you saying that `console.log(dataObject );` and `console.log(DataEntryObj);` shows the same thing?